# There exists infinitely many irrationals within a range of reals?

Tags: proof-verification, irrational-numbers

**Theorem:** There exists infinitely many irrationals in a range of reals.

**Proof:**
Let the range be $R=(a,b)$ where $a<b$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

Suppose some numbers $n_1\ldots n_k\in R$ where each number is greater than the one before, then $a<n_1<\cdots<n_k<b$. From this it follows

\begin{align}
a&<n_1\\
n_1&<n_2\\
&\vdots\\
n_{k-1}&<n_k\\
n_k&<b
\end{align}

So

$$
a+\sum\limits_{i=1}^k n_i<b+\sum\limits_{i=1}^k n_i\qquad\therefore a<b
$$

Because $k$ can be arbitrarily big, and the truth values of $a<b$ does not depend on $k$, we can conclude that there are infinitely many numbers on a given range. We will now use the fact that the distance between two numbers -irrationals too- is always finite.

Because there are infinitely many numbers in a range where $a<b$ and infinity can be divided into infinite finite parts, then there must be infinite irrationals in that range. $\blacksquare$

---

My question is, is this argument valid? Any *not-so-right* steps?

Comment: **PD:** I would like ti know how the vertical dots should be used in this case with MathJax, as I don't see them right.

Comment: In latex it is \vdots

Comment: @joeb I used them like that, but they are not centered.

Comment: I don't follow the idea of the proof. You seem to be pulling $k$ numbers out of a hat, then somehow "prove" the hypothesis that $a \lt b$.

Comment: $k$ is just the number of numbers between $a$ and $b$. At first finite, but the conclusion is that $k$ can be infinity because it cancels when grouping all the inequalities.

Comment: Yes you do seem to be arguing in the wrong direction. Another thing about your arguement, what happens if one of the $n_i = 0$. Then $a \prod_i n_i < b \prod_i n_i$ does not imply $a < b$. It doesn't matter anyway, because you don't need anything to imply $a<b$, you were given this from the start.

Comment: What you've written makes no sense to me. Nothing in your argument says anything at all about irrational numbers. I suggest you start over. Can you find ONE irrational number between $0$ and $1$? When you have done that, find ONE irrational number between $a$ and $b$. Then think about how you could know you could find more.

Comment: @joeb That shows there are an infinite number of rationals in the interval.  The question was to prove there are an infinite number of **irrationals**.

Comment: @MarkFischler But the fact that the distance between two irrationals is finite and there are infinitely many reals between a range doesn't imply that there are infinitely many irrationals within that range?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to, say, construct a bijection (or injections both ways would be sufficient due to Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein) between an arbitrary range and all of $\mathbb{R}$? That tells you the range is uncountable, and you presumably know that rationals are countable, thus this uncountable set of reals minus a countable set of rationals in the range gives you an uncountable (infinite) set.

Comment: @joeb That is exactly what I've done, just in another words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your proof misses the point.  Aside from the fact that you start with an assumption about the existence of a set of ordered intermediate values of arbitrary size, and spend most of your time proving that $a<b$, which was already given, the problem is that what you have shown is that there are infinitely many reals between any two unequal reals.  But how do you know that almost all of them aren't rational, leaving only finitely many irrationals?

I would start by proving that between any two rational numbers $q_1$ and $q_2$  with $q_1<q_2$ there exists at least one irrational, by proving that 
$q_1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(q_2-q_1)$ is irrational.  (The proof of that is a lot like the
proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.)

Then I would use the fact that at least one rational number must exist between any two unequal reals (proved by using a denominator bigger than twice the reciprocal of the distance between the reals).  Apply that to $a$ and $b$, getting a rational $q_x$, and apply it again between $a$ and $q_x$ getting another rational $q_y$.

Now for any given $N$ you can break up the interval between $q_x$ and $q_y$ into $N+2$ rational sub-intervals and by the first part of the proof you can slot $N+1>N$ irrationals, one in each interval.  So for any arbitrary $N$ there are more than $N$ irrationals in the interval.