# Prove that set $[\sqrt5;+\infty)$ is uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Prove that  set $[\sqrt5;+\infty)$ is uncountable.

This is what I did.

I know that set of irrationals is uncountable.If we take subset of given set $[\sqrt5;r]$ where $r$ is real  number [from](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158721/there-exists-infinitely-many-irrationals-within-a-range-of-reals) this we know there is infinitely many irrationals at that range.So $[\sqrt5;r]$ is uncountable and because it is subset of $[\sqrt5;+\infty)$ follows that this set is also uncountable.

Is my proof right?If not how prove that set is uncountable?

Comment: It's correct using the cited result.  You could also do this.  If it were countable, the function $f(x)=-x+\sqrt{5}$ shows that $(-\infty, \sqrt5]$ is also countable.  Since the union of two countable sets is countable, so is $\mathbb{R}$, a contradiction.

Comment: @Randall You wanted to say the function $f(x) = -x + 2\sqrt 5$. Another approach is that $g(x) = \sqrt 5 + e^x$ maps $\Bbb R$ injectively into $[\sqrt 5, +\infty)$.

Comment: @Randall Can you explain why $f(x)$ shows that $(-\infty,\sqrt5]$ is also countable?

Comment: It is from my topology lecture notes @user.

Comment: Well @unit1991  you first need to apply the recommended edit above.  But this function gives a bijection between the two sets so they have the same cardinality.

Comment: $[\sqrt{5},+\infty)$ has the same size as $\Bbb R$ so is uncountable.

Comment: That a set contains infinitely many irrationals does *not* imply it has uncountably many. That invalidates your idea.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma how to prove that $[\sqrt5,+\infty)$ has same size as $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Cantor Bernstein is easiest: $|[\sqrt{5}, +\infty)| \le |\Bbb R|$ by inclusion. And $f(x)= 10+ \arctan(x)$ maps $\Bbb R$ injectively into $|[\sqrt{5}, +\infty)|$ so $|\Bbb R| \le |[\sqrt{5}, +\infty)|$ and hence equality.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma How one would prove that $f(x)=10+arctan(x)$ gives injection from $R$ into $[\sqrt5,+\infty)$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Range of $arctanx$ is $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and with that function we are getting values outside of range?Maybe I am wrong here

Comment: Not if you add $10$: the values are all $>\sqrt{5}$ easily. $\arctan(x)$ is an injection and so is the modified version.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  I was thinking about bijection. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since op was curious to see an easy method to show that $[\sqrt{5},\infty)$ is uncountable, we provide two alternative proofs.

**Proof 1:**

$(\sqrt{5},\infty)$ is equipotent to $\mathbb{R}$ via $f:(\sqrt{5},\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $$f(x)=\ln(x-\sqrt{5})$$
So $[\sqrt{5},\infty)$ contains an uncountable subset, and is thus uncountable (If it were countable, then every subset of it would be countable, which is clearly not the case here).

**Proof 2:**

We construct an explicit bijection between $[\sqrt{5},\infty)$ and $(0,1)$.

Firstly, we note that $[\sqrt{5},\infty)$ is equipotent to $[0,1)$ via the map $g:[\sqrt{5},\infty)\to[0,1)$ defined by $$g(x) = 1-\frac{1}{(x-\sqrt{5})+1}$$

We define a map $h:[0,1)\to(0,1)$ defined by
$$h(x)=
\begin{cases}
1/2&\text{ if } x= 0\\
1/2^{n+1}&\text{ if } x=1/2^{n}\text{ for some natural }n\geq 1\\
x&\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I leave it to the reader to verify that $h$ is a bijection.

By defining $f=h\circ g:[\sqrt{5},\infty)\to(0,1)$, we get an explicit bijection between the two sets. Hopefully it is known to OP that $(0,1)$ is uncountable. This fact however is not hard to show, as the OP seems to be aware that the reals are uncountable, and there are many bijections (uncountably many, even) from the open unit interval to the reals.